# Is it possible to change XML values using Firetuner?

Tags: civilization-5, mods

I was wondering if it is possible to change values predefined in the core XML files in a running game using Firetuner (or some other method) without having to restart the game?

Answer (score 2):

Find config.ini in Documents\My Games\Sid Meier's Civilization 5.  Edit the first value so that EnableTuner=1.  Now start up Firetuner from the SDK menu.  Finally, load up your Civ 5 game like you would normally.  Switch back to Firetuner and marvel at the power you have to setup scenarios, including:

- Live modification of values in any of the database tables
- Ability to add just about anything to any civ, including techs, money, culture, etc.
- Ability to modify the map on the fly
- And much,much more

Just discovered this myself, it should make testing out some of the crazy scenarios we have wondered about MUCH easier.  As one would expect, it is not possible to earn achievements on a game once this has been used.

Comment: I know the basic functionality of FireTuner, but I could not find any method to change values (e.g. from the GlobalDefines.xml) inside the game. I thought it should be in the database part, but I could not find anything there.

Comment: Have you read Kael's modding guide?  My understanding is that all the values from the XML files are loaded into database tables during the game, so you should be able to modify them from there.  I admittedly haven't played around it with it much yet.  I'll experiment more when I get a chance and expand my answer if I learn more.